# How to write conditionals(if, else) to display ui elements based on user input?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, conditional-statements, shinydashboard

I'm trying to show different options in `selectInput` panel based on a condition(number of days given through `dateRangeInput`).

Basically, what I'm trying to do is: the user selects dates in `dateRangeInput` and(number of days will be calculated from that input) and the options in `selectInput` has to be updated(if number of days is less than 15, 'weekly' shouldn't be an option & if number of days is less than 62, 'monthly' shouldn't be an option).

Here's what I tried seeing [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/conditionalpanel-demo.html) for `conditionalPanel`(documentation only had example for `if` and I don't know javascript. So, i couldn't do more):
UI:

```
ui_function <- fluidPage(
  # initiating side bar layout 
  sidebarLayout(
    # all inputs in side panel of side bar layout
    sidebarPanel(
      # I'm taking date range as input 
      dateRangeInput(inputId = 'date_range',
                     label = paste('range from Jan 1, 2017 to Dec 31, 2018 for 4 departments'),
                     start = as.Date("2017-01-01"), end = as.Date("2017-02-28"),
                     min = as.Date("2017-01-01"), max = as.Date("2018-12-31"),
                     separator = " to ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                     startview = 'year', weekstart = 1
      ),
            conditionalPanel(
        # as long as number of days is not more than 15(more than 2 weeks) you can't have weekly aggregation. So you only have daily aggregation
        condition =  "input.date_range[2] - input.date_range[1] < 15",
        selectInput(inputId = "roll_up_input", 
                    label = "Choose a roll up range",
                    choices = c("Daily" = "Daily"),
                    selected = "Daily"),
        # as long as number of days is not more than 60(more than 2 months) you can't have monthly aggregation. So you only have daily, weekly aggregation
        condition =  "input.date_range[2] - input.date_range[1] < 31",
        selectInput(inputId = "roll_up_input", 
                    label = "Choose a roll up range",
                    choices = c("Daily" = "Daily",
                                "Weekly"="Weekly"),
                    selected = "Weekly"),
        # as long as number of days is not more than 182(more than 2 quarters) you can't have quarterly aggregation. So you only have daily, weekly, monthly aggregation
        condition = "input.date_range[2] - input.date_range[1] < 91",
        selectInput(inputId = "roll_up_input", 
                    label = "Choose a roll up range",
                    choices = c("Daily" = "Daily",
                                "Weekly"="Weekly",
                                "Monthly"="Monthly",
                                "Quarterly"="Quarterly"),
                    selected = "Weekly"),
        )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # checking if calculation of number of days is working properly.
      verbatimTextOutput("days_selected")
    )
  ))
```

and here's my server function:

```
server_function <- function(input, output) {
  # calculate number of days
  no_selected_days <- renderText({as.integer(input$date_range[2] - input$date_range[1])})
  no_days <- reactive({as.integer(input$date_range[2] - input$date_range[1])})


  output$days_selected <- renderText({paste("You have selected ",input$date_range[1], "to",input$date_range[2],"that is", no_days(), "days")})
}
```

I've also tried creating a reactive variable in server and using it for conditional like:
in server:

```
no_selected_days <- renderText({as.integer(input$date_range[2] - input$date_range[1])})
```

and in ui:

```
condition = "output.no_selected_days < 91"
```

and nothing worked.

Also the problem is, that `selectInput` doesn't show up at all in my UI(something with the conditional may have gone wrong).

(Yes, i want same `inputId` for all `selectInput`s, so i could use the input in server function).

So, how do I only show some options in `selectInput` based on another input. Or is there any completely different or better way to do this?

---

**EDIT 1:**
I've tried using `updateSelectInput`. it didn't work too.
my server code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  no_days <- reactive({as.integer(input$date_range[2] - input$date_range[1])})
  output$selected_is <- renderText({paste("You have selected ",input$date_range[1], "to",input$date_range[2],"that is", no_days(), "days")})


  observe({
    if (no_days() < 15)
      {updateSelectInput(session, "select_roll_up",
                      label = paste("Select input label"),
                      choices = c("Daily"),
                      selected = "Daily")
      }
    else if (no_days() < 63)
    {updateSelectInput(session, "select_roll_up",
                        label = paste("Select input label"),
                        choices = c("Daily", "Weekly"),
                        selected = "Weekly")
      }
    else (no_days() < 96)
    {updateSelectInput(session, "select_roll_up",
                        label = paste("Select input label"),
                        choices = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"),
                        selected = "Monthly")
      }
  })
}
```

and UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The checkbox group controls the select input"),
  dateRangeInput(inputId = 'date_range',
                 label = paste('range from Jan 1, 2017 to Dec 31, 2018 for 4 departments'),
                 start = as.Date("2017-01-01"), end = as.Date("2017-02-28"),
                 min = as.Date("2017-01-01"), max = as.Date("2018-12-31"),
                 separator = " to ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                 startview = 'year', weekstart = 1
  ),
  selectInput("select_roll_up", "Select input",
              c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quartely", "Yearly")),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_is")
)
```

This always executed last conditional(else condition above) and printed "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", irrespective of number of days.

Comment: Shiny has update functions for inputs for cases such as these. See `updateSelectInput()`. You can use it to change the choices from a reactive environment in the server function

Comment: @Rohit please check the edit and reply me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last else statement should not have a condition without an if. If you remove the condition, or add an `if` before the condition it'll work:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The checkbox group controls the select input"),
  dateRangeInput(inputId = 'date_range',
                 label = paste('range from Jan 1, 2017 to Dec 31, 2018 for 4 departments'),
                 start = as.Date("2017-01-01"), end = as.Date("2017-02-28"),
                 min = as.Date("2017-01-01"), max = as.Date("2018-12-31"),
                 separator = " to ", format = "dd/mm/yy",
                 startview = 'year', weekstart = 1
  ),
  selectInput("select_roll_up", "Select input",
              c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quartely", "Yearly")),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_is")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  no_days <- reactive({as.integer(input$date_range[2] - input$date_range[1])})
  output$selected_is <- renderText({paste("You have selected ",input$date_range[1], "to",input$date_range[2],"that is", no_days(), "days")})


  observe({
    if (no_days() < 15)
    {updateSelectInput(session, "select_roll_up",
                       label = paste("Select input label"),
                       choices = c("Daily"),
                       selected = "Daily")
    }
    else if (no_days() < 63)
    {updateSelectInput(session, "select_roll_up",
                       label = paste("Select input label"),
                       choices = c("Daily", "Weekly"),
                       selected = "Weekly")
    }
    else if(no_days() < 96)
    # OR JUST
    # else
    {updateSelectInput(session, "select_roll_up",
                       label = paste("Select input label"),
                       choices = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"),
                       selected = "Monthly")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```